# Unable to connect with WPA2 android

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am using following code to connect with WPA2 in android (I can connect with WEP and WPA). But I am getting only 'Scanning' status. And I am unable to connect with WPA2 network. Can you tell me what changes I need to make this code relevant with wpa2 WiFi.

```
private boolean saveWepConfigAndEnableNetwork(String ssid, String pass) {
    isAlreadyPresend = false;
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\""; // IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
    wc = checkPreviousConfiguration(wc);
    wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
    wc.priority = 40;
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + pass + "\"";

    wc.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + pass + "\""; // This is the WEP Password
    wc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

    boolean res1 = wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int res = 0;
    if(isAlreadyPresend){
        res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
    }else{
        res = wifi.updateNetwork(wc);
    }

    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
    boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration();
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es);
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b);
    return b;
}

// Check if this SSID is already stored. If it is, return that
// configuration.
// If not, return the configuration being tested.
public WifiConfiguration checkPreviousConfiguration(WifiConfiguration wc) {
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
        if (config.SSID.equals(wc.SSID)){
            isAlreadyPresend = true;
            return config;
        }
    }
    return wc;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code which worked for me to connect with WPA2

```
// Adding a WPA or WPA2 network
public static void changeNetworkWPA(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid, String password) {
    WifiConfiguration config = changeNetworkCommon(ssid);
    // Hex passwords that are 64 bits long are not to be quoted.
    config.preSharedKey = quoteNonHex(password, 64);
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); // For WPA
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); // For WPA2
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    updateNetwork(wifiManager, config);
}
```

Code: From [Zxing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/wifi/WifiConfigManager.java)

Comment: The code is taken from: com.google.zxing.client.android.wifi.WifiConfigManager.java

Answer (score 0):

just to enrich the excellent answer above,

Android supports different WIFI security mechanism such as **WEP** and **WPA/WPA2** which are described under **IEEE 802.11** norm.
The Android `WifiManager` API lets you set up the WIFI network parameters of your application in order to connect to a particular access point (your wifi box) using a particular protocol.

for example, in case of WPA/WPA2, by performing the **key challenge handshake** that authorizes connection on a WPA/WPA2 networks.
Now, to successfully connect to a WPA or WPA2 network *you just need to add the supported protocols, cipher methods and key management methods that your device will try to use when connecting to it* otherwise they won’t have a chance to understand each other.

If you are using a **PreShared key as authentication** with WPA/WPA2 (which is used in most part of the real world wifi hotspots) then you are basically using a symmetric key phrase that’s know in advance by your device and your access point,
Assuming you use a WPA/WPA2 network (Not WEP nor Enterprise WPA2 server crt authentication)

Remember WPA and WPA2 differ in the type of cipher for the packages the first on uses generally **TKIP** and the other one  uses **AES** ( similar CCMP) which is more secure.
that say, you can have confusing combinations of  cipher methods using the same  WIFI protection standard as for example

```
WPA2:
NETWORK USE KEY CCMP=[WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]
WPA:
NETWORK USE KEY CCMP=[WPA-PSK-CCMP][ESS]
NETWORK USE KEY TKIP=[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][ESS]
NETWORK USE KEY TKIP=[WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS]
```

So the best approach in case you are interested in access to both WPA and WPA2 networks with a keyphrase as mentioned above, resumes on **explicitly  adding the corresponding supported config options to be as open as possible for the type of network you want to potentially connect** and once config is done, you just need to add the network to use by your app and start the connection challenge.

you can use this code , it took me a while but it works great! for ***WPA and WPA2*** using same wifi configuration.

```
public static boolean addNetwork8(Context context, String ssid, String password) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    // setup a wifi configuration
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
    wc.preSharedKey = "\""+ password +"\"";
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    // connect to and enable the connection
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);


    return true;
}
```

and then you can call the method  wherever you need to connect to a WPA/WPA2 network

```
boolean added = Connectivity.addNetwork8(this, network, password);
    Log.d(TAG, "Network added " + added);
```

Enjoy, working code!!

**PS:**
i did not have to specify authalgorithm config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN) ; for WAP/WAP2 i assume that it's because it uses x0  , luckily .

```
/** Open System authentication (required for WPA/WPA2) */public static 
final int OPEN = 0;
```